# Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm inserting a very basic Google map into my page and the zoom control and streetmap icon are not visible, however if I place my mouse over where they should be I can zoom the map and enter streetview. 
So the controls are there just not visible.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<apikey>&sensor=false&region=IT">
</script>

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: latlng,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

[image: Missing controls]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps zoom control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879544/google-maps-zoom-control)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

That is definitely a CSS issue that you have with your code. Look for CSS that is applying to all images like:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That was it thanks, I have a responsive page layout and was following the suggestion in [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) to set the maximum image width to 100%. I fixed it using `#map_container img { max-width:none; }`.

Comment: On first search i didnt find suche code in my css BUT i am using Twitter Bootstrap framework which uses this fluid images tweak.

Comment: Yes, caution to all Twitter Bootstrap users! Their CSS will cause this. Adding `.gmnoprint img { max-width: none; }` (as stated by @Pete) anywhere after the bootstrap CSS inclusion will fix this.

Comment: Zubr Foundation also does this :/

Comment: Been stuck on this all day long! Thank you skarE. Thank you, thank you, thank you! I also changed `max-height: none` to make this work. Did I say thank you?

Answer (score 46):

I had this problem, the fix was to include this CSS ...

```
.gmnoprint img { max-width: none; }
```

The CSS selector `.gmnoprint img` gets to all images [img] on the Google Map [gm] controls that are non printing [noprint].  In my case `max-width` had been set globally to 100%.  Unsetting this fixed the issue.

Comment: Sometimes a sledgehammer may be needed:
    `.gmnoprint img { max-width: none !important; }`

Comment: And a word of encouragement for testers of this fix: I applied it, accurately, and saw it not work. Went on to other tasks. Eventually, after a day or so, ended up cleaning up other problems with the html in my page -- removed an extra </div>, got my containers all containing the right stuff, yada yada -- when, like magic, my tools just showed up on the next page refresh. The html/css world is a touchy one; keep calm and code on.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution to reach only for **google map**

```
.gmnoprint img {
    max-width: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and it turned out in my case NOT to be a CSS issue.  In my case, the Content-Security-Policy header on our site was blocking certain images from being rendered. In this case it was blocking the street view images (loaded from a *.ggpht.com uri) and the button icons which use inline svg data specified using the data: scheme.  To fix this, I added the following to the Content-Security-Policy header:

```
img-src data: 'self' https://*.googleapis.com https://*.google.com https://*.gstatic.com https://*.ggpht.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that on the moment it's not even possible to show the full size zoom slider on touch devices (ipad etc). Here's the documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html

**google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL** displays a mini-zoom control, consisting of only + and - buttons. This style is appropriate for small maps. **On touch devices, this control displays as + and - buttons that are responsive to touch events.**

**google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE** displays the standard zoom slider control. **On touch devices, this control displays as + and - buttons that are responsive to touch events.**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a variant, with the offending css looking like:

```html
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

So, an additional line is needed:

```
#map_div img {
   max-width: none !important;
   max-height: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking this might be a problem with the browser or the code within the page that you're embedding this map.

If I look at this simple hello world code, the maps controls show up fine. I geocoded this map to the same location as your sample, so its not anything to do with the location.

What happens when you use this sample?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=true&region=it">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.38686, 8.91927);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: latlng,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        },
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```