# Google Maps zoom control is messed up

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I use the Google Maps API (v.3) to show a map with a couple of markers. I recently noticed that the control used to zoom the map is messed up (it wasn't always like this). I have no idea what the cause is.

[image]

#### Update

This post originally had a link to a page where you could view the issue, but the link is broken now, so I've removed it.

Comment: This issue doesn't happen with Bootstrap uf you use the is map_canvas as the map div id.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Your CSS messed it up. Remove `max-width: 100%;` in line 814 and zoom controls will look fine again. To avoid such bugs use more specific selectors in your CSS.

Comment: This is also true if you're using Twitter's Bootstrap, they have a img { max-width:100%} that messes this up. It should be fixed in the 2.0.2 branch

Comment: Many CSS reset files also have `img {max-width:100%;}` set.

Comment: Awesome!  I too was having problems with this, and I just recently moved to bootstrap css.  Mucho ++++

Comment: Had the same issue with jquery mobile. They have `.ui-mobile img {max-width: 100%;}` in their css which had to be removed.

Comment: Interesting that it's bootstrap that causes this. Made me nuts for a while.

Comment: to fix that at bootstrap just give your maps div class google-maps

Comment: @SamyMassoud great tip, any idea if Foundation also has something similar? Can't find it in the docs

Comment: @ithil Giving your Google Maps element an ID of `googlemap` or `map_canvas` or a class of `map_canvas` should do the trick.

Comment: @ithil Yes, Foundation does something similar. The trick by Aligned works very nice to fix this.

Answer (score 80):

```css
#myMap_canvas img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

fixed it for me, but I also wanted to point out the comment on the question by @Ben, "This issue doesn't happen with Bootstrap if you use the is map_canvas as the map div id". He's right. I'm not using Bootstrap, but the problem started happening after I changed the div id.

Setting it back to map_canvas fixed it without the max-width change.

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Bootstrap, just give it "google-maps" class. This worked for me.

As an alternative you might reset everything for the google map div as a kind of last-resort solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="mappins-map"><div>
```

CSS:

```css
.mappins-map img { 
    max-width: none !important; 
    height: auto !important; 
    background: none !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Just share @Max-Favilli answer:

With latest version of google maps api you need this:

```
<style>
.gm-style img { max-width: none; }
.gm-style label { width: auto; display: inline; }
</style>
```

Thanks to @Max-Favilli

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339767/3070027

Answer (score 5):

If you're a Twitter Bootstrap user you should add this line to your CSS:

```css
.gmnoprint img { max-width: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well and using

```css
.google-maps img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

didn't work. I eventually used

```css
.google-maps img {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: !important might not be necessary if your selector is more specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Yahoo's Pure CSS, give your div the "google-maps" class like Bootstrap, and put this rule in your CSS:

```css
.google-maps img {
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
}
```

As far as I can tell, Pure CSS has no way of fixing this issue on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Those options you guys told me didn´t work for my website.

I use Bootstrap V3 and focussed on the functionality. The main reason was that i had given my map a different ID then the CSS file used to display the zoom bar with the yellow streetvieuw guy

I renamed map_canvas to mapholder and then it worked for me! Thanks anyways for the hints that i should look into the CSS files!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions, and others from other forums to no avail.  it was really annoying because I have another non-Wordpress site where the code worked perfectly. (I was trying to display a Google map in a Wordpress page, but the zoom and Streetview controls were distorted).

The solution I did was to create a new html file (copy paste all the code into Notepad and name it xyz.html, save as type "all files"). Then upload/ftp it up to website, and setup a new Wordpress page and use an embed function.  When editing the page go to the text editor (not the visual editor) and copy/type:

http://page URL width="900" height="950">

If you change the dimensions, remember to change it in both arguments above, or you get weird results.

There we go - might not be as clever as some other answers, but it worked for me!  Evidence here: http://a-bc.co.uk/latitude-longitude-finder/