# Google maps API v3 user interface

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, interface

I have a very small stylistic problem in my google maps.

I am using google maps API v3 and the problem is the left slider which looks like this:

[image]

I can't understand why or where i searched the web but I didn't made any changes to the map config so how did this happen. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps zoom control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879544/google-maps-zoom-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your css / stylesheets and look for any rule interfering with the map layout.

What you describe here happened to me too because of some rule defined in a component of  the bootstrap framework (http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: I am using bootstrap forgot to tell So to update the boostrap or what ?

Comment: i found the rule it is

Bootstrap v2.3.2
in the css file line 102
`img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}`

max-width property is doing the problem so use i target my map and set the max-width property to none and everything is working great

`#map-canvas img{
    max-width: none;
}`

Comment: I do not remember what rule caused the issue and do not know if an update has been released which fixes this issue. I am afraid you need to find the rules causing this issue and change their scopes to exclude the map