# Google Map Pan Control Disordered on IE 11

Tags: css, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `Google Maps API v3` in my application. Maps Pan control isn't displaying properly on IE 10 and IE 11.

[image].

It's working fine on Chrome, Mozilla and IE8, IE9. I can't figure out the way to resolve it.

on Stackoverflow, a nearly similar question is posted here:  [Google Maps zoom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879544/google-maps-zoom-control)

but not solution is not application. Definitely, it's the CSS issue, but I couldn't resolve it. I've checked in IE developer tool for any css class overriding, but no luck.

Have anyone faced the similar problem or anyone had any solution for this?

EDIT:  The basic map is also disordered in my IE 11 version.![enter image description here]
[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]
-- Anil

Comment: It doesn't happen for me with a [**basic map**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) , we need to see your implementation.

Comment: @Dr.Molle The basic map is disordered on my IE 11. attaching screenshot to my question Edit as well.

Comment: Open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4563) in the issue tracker (for IE10...)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. found solution by setting opacity to 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as @geocodezip suggested, it's a bug till today in Google map API and best solution for it is to use css.

use below css on the page :

```
.gmnoprint div[title^="Pan"]
 {
        filter:alpha(opacity=0)!important;
 }
```

hope it would help others and save time.

-Anil

Answer (score 1):

I just added the styling to my CSS , and fix

```
.gmnoprint div[title^="Pan"] {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked for me too and the one above didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An important addition to non-English localizations:
You must use in style not "Pan", but the text specific to your locale. For example, for Russian localization - "Пан".
Hover your mouse on a button of pan Control and look pop-up hint. In style the first 3 letters from it are used.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I've found that the above CSS isn't enough because we next get "+" for zoom in/out for street view.  I made a slight modification...turn off all title items except the one we don't want hidden.

```
.gmnoprint div[title]
{
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
.gmnoprint div[title^="Exit Street View"]
{
    opacity: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party I know, but when I came across this issue I implemented the following fix for my applications using Google Maps V3 which I know is similar to what has already been posted here, but just in case it helps as I know how damn frustrating these sorts of issues can be!

```
<script>
        var doc = document.documentElement;
        doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html[data-useragent*='Trident/7.0'] div[title^="Zoom"]
     {
            opacity: 0 !important;
     }
     html[data-useragent*='Trident/7.0'] div[title^="Pan"]
     {
            opacity: 0 !important;
     }
    </style>
```