# Why does CSS resets have max-width:100%

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I was working on google map javascript v3 api and found out the `max-width:100%` that is being called is messing the controls in the google map. Reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879544/google-maps-zoom-control).

I wonder why does CSS resets have `img {max-width: 100%;}` and what happen if I just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to remove img { max-width: 100%; } you just give an id in your map div and add

## map-id img{max-width:none;}

Answer (score -1):

If you remove `img { max-width: 100%; }` it will no longer make your images responsive. And since you're using google maps I'd assume that the maps would no longer fit within the user's screen.