# Google Places API, additional marker (manually added) to results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

My javascript isn't too hot, I'm trying to add a manual marker onto a number of locations gathered from the Google Places API.

I followed **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775774/seperate-marker-for-each-location-type-in-google-places-api)** to get to my following code (with a few amendments):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var infowindow;
      var service ;
    base_Icon_festival = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.png";
    shadow_festival = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.shadow.png";

      function initialize(lat,lng) 
      {
        var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
          center: origin,
          zoom: 14,
      scrollwheel: false,

        });

        var request = {
          location: origin,
          radius: 2500,
          types: ['train_station','bus_station','subway_station','airport']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

    base_Icon_train = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png";               
        base_Icon_bus = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png";  
        base_Icon_subway = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png";   
        base_Icon_airport = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png";  

      function createMarker(place) {

    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker;
        var icon_to_use;

    if (place.types.indexOf('train_station') != -1) {
           icon_to_use = base_Icon_train;
    } else if (place.types.indexOf('bus_station') != -1) {
           icon_to_use = base_Icon_bus;
    } else if (place.types.indexOf('subway_station') != -1) {
           icon_to_use = base_Icon_subway;
    } else if (place.types.indexOf('airport') != -1) {
           icon_to_use = base_Icon_airport;
    } 

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: icon_to_use  
    });

        var content='<strong style="font-size:1.2em">'+place.name+'</strong>'+
                    '<br/><strong>Latitude: </strong>'+placeLoc.lat()+
                    '<br/><strong>Longitude: </strong>'+placeLoc.lng()+
                    '<br/><strong>Type: </strong>'+place.types[0];

        //make a request for further details
        service.getDetails({reference:place.reference}, function (place, status) 
                                    {
                                      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
                                      {
                                        more_content='<hr/><strong><a href="'+place.url+'" target="details">Details</a>';

                                        if(place.website)
                                        {
                                          more_content+='<br/><br/><strong><a href="'+place.website+'" target="details">'+place.website+'</a>';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

          infowindow.setContent(content+more_content);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){initialize(<?php echo $coordinated; ?>);});
    </script>
    <div id="map" style="height:400px;"></div>
```

Now I would like to manually add another marker which is located at the center of the map (ie, the variable origin which is currently being pulled from a PHP variable - `var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);`). I also need this marker to have a different icon associated with it (`base_Icon_festival` and `shadow_festival` respectively).

I'm not sure how to manually add another marker to the ones already gathered by the places API?

End goal: have a festival icon marker at the center of the map and a number of public transport markers surrounding it, resulting code to go on individual festival pages of a website.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Adding a [single marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers), even a custom marker is covered pretty well in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Google Maps API, markers are added to the map by creating a Marker object and setting the map property.  This is the snippet in your code that adds the existing Markers.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location,
  icon: icon_to_use  
});
```

To add a new marker you would just replace the position and icon properties with your values.

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: origin,
  icon: shadow_festival 
});
```

This code can probably be added at the end of the Callback function and if you don't need the actual marker object for anything else, you can just create the Marker object and never assign it.

There is an example from the Google Maps API docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

Comment: You mean like this:
`base_Icon_festival = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.png";
 shadow_festival = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.shadow.png";

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
 new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: origin,
   icon: base_Icon_festival 
 });
        }
      }`

- if so, it doesn't seem to work...?

Comment: origin is a co-ordinate pulled from a PHP variable like (53.068864,-2.526276). See last bit of code in question. Map I'm not sure...? Javascript is VERY new to me...

Comment: I found the problem.  The origin is declared in the initialize function and not accessible in callback.  Declare origin outside the initialize function and you should be good.  The shadow is hard to see over the satellite btw.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew but still for the life of me can't get this to work! I've tried declaring origin outside of the initialized function but no dice. Would you mind pasting up a solution on pastebin or something? - Thanks again for the help, cheers for the tip on the shadow/satellite.

Comment: I posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/backpackcoder/d4ccf695b756de0507ec#file-stackoverflow-answer).  It works in Chrome and IE10.