# Google map controls do not display properly

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map)

I've been trying out on different browsers, OS's, canvas sizes, all the same (note the place where zoom bar is supposed to be).. Any one by chance ran into this issue?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbVoK.jpg
This is how I initialize the map (really nothing special):

```
var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: mapCenter
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), options);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/975/), post other code, problem may be in somewhere else.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map