# google maps cut off in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I got a strange problem with the googlemaps js api. I generate a map and it shows perfectly in all browsers but in chrome. There it is somehow cut off or zoomed too much, so that the controls on the left side are cut off.

See this screenshot: [image]

I searched for the problem but couldn't find a working solution, adding

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

like I read in a few threads didn't help..

Here is my code:

js:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.458641, 13.380887);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

html:

```
<div id='Map'></div>
```

css:

```
#Map {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border: 1px solid #000;
float: right;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map)

Comment: that's the solution! Thank you very much! I didn't find this thread during my research..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to geocodezip in this thread: [Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map)

Adding

```
#Map img {
max-width: none;
}
```

to the css did the trick.