# Google Maps Street View Icon Missing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The Person Icon that represents the Street View on Google maps seems to be having issue on my insert.  I am using the v3 api and The Icon placement is there but the icon seems missing or distorted.

If you look at the image something is there but it disappears on hover.  Any ideas what could cause this.

I believe its could be to do with some of my pages code as if i do a vanilla version it seems ok, but i am not targeting this at all and was wondering if anyone else has come across this and might have an idea etc

[image]

Comment: Never saw that but maybe you can fix it by setting the [StreetViewControlOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewControlOptions) explicit.

Comment: That is a css problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map)

Comment: @geocodezip your right thanks to the life of me this did not come up in searches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a CSS issue. Look for CSS that is applying to all images like:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yeah i found this little code: img { border : 0; max-width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;} @vinod_vh thanks

Comment: I did the other day it did not register, sorry

Comment: I hate it when I figure out that an awnser is just copied straight from another question.

Answer (score 4):

Select only Google Maps and keep the rest of your site responsive

```
.gm-style img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set:

```
img {
    max-width: none;
}
```