# Google map zoom control "squished"

Tags: google-maps

Take a look at my google map, quite simple, and simpler css...
the thing i don't understand is why the + and _ and slider is all squished and compressed... 
i don't have modify/touched it with nothing...

http://studioteknik.co/brasseursillimites.com/detaillants/

can you know what make the map "buggy" ?

where i can control this anyway... i dont have overwrite anything with css, but since it buggy, i like to know where this is controlled

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found : [Zoom control and streetview not showing on my Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511436/zoom-control-and-streetview-not-showing-on-my-google-map)

and : [Google Maps API V3 : weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471830/google-maps-api-v3-weird-ui-display-glitches-with-screenshot)

In short, add this to your CSS file (updating the ID as necessary):

```css
#map-canvas img { 
  max-width: none; 
  max-height: none;
}
```